# PHP PDO fetchall - class

Tags: php, oop, pdo

This is the problem:

One class which is extended by few other classes. Something like this:

```
 class a { 
 private $propertyA;
  public function getPropertyA()
  {
   return $this->propertyA;
  }
 }

 class b extends a
 {
  public function getPropertyA()
  {
   return $this->propertyA;
  }
 }

class c extends a
{
 public function getPropertyA()
 {
  return $this->propertyA;
 }
}
```

There's a PDO mysql call to fetch the results from DB using the http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php with 'class' argument and specifying either 'b' or 'c' as the class I want to instantiate. All this works perfectly fine; but suppose classes 'b' & 'c' share several methods.

Perhaps obvious way would be to move the methods common for both classes to class 'a'. But this is a problem; if in the PDO fetchAll I specify the target class as 'a' I won't get access to methods and properties of child classes. If I specify the target class for example 'b' I will get access to methods extended from 'a' but not to properties (which will have been instantiated in 'b')

I hope this question makes sense; if not I'll try to polish it some.

**edited for better clarity**
So...question would then be how to instantiate the object using PDO's fetchAll-class where part of the logic resides in the parent class. In such case methods are avaiable (through inheritance) but data are not assigned to properties (because the fetchAll instantiates the child class).

Comment: you need to polish this some...

Comment: This is a bit confusing. But it might be that you want to take a look at "late binding".

Comment: Do you simply need to use the `protected` keyword instead of the `private` keyword for your properties?